# fdisk showing inconstant data, it shows /dev/sda twice

Tags: partitioning, fdisk, disk-management, disk-image

I boot a laptop off of an Ubuntu USB drive. I want to to use dd to image the laptop so I can have a copy before I format it. When I do `fdisk -l` I get

```
root@ubuntu:/mnt/nfs/volume2/drive2/fpp/test# fdisk -l /dev/sda 
Disk /dev/sda: 29.9 GiB, 32080200192 bytes, 62656641 sectors
Disk model: Flash Drive     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x20ac7dda

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1       3224498923 3657370039  432871117 206.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       3272020941 5225480974 1953460034 931.5G 16 Hidden FAT16
/dev/sda3                0          0          0     0B 6f unknown
/dev/sda4         50200576  974536369  924335794 440.8G  0 Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
root@ubuntu:/mnt/nfs/volume2/drive2/fpp/test#
```

It seems that the first listing there is my USB thumb drive and the second is laptops actual drive. Shouldn't the laptops disk and the USB drive have different drive letters?

EDIT: Below is the output of `fdisk -l`

```
root@ubuntu:/mnt/nfs/volume2/drive2/fpp/test# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.99 GiB, 2109763584 bytes, 4120632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 218.102 MiB, 229629952 bytes, 448496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 55.48 MiB, 58159104 bytes, 113592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 64.79 MiB, 67915776 bytes, 132648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 51.4 MiB, 53522432 bytes, 104536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 31.9 MiB, 32595968 bytes, 63664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 29.9 GiB, 32080200192 bytes, 62656641 sectors
Disk model: Flash Drive     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x20ac7dda

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1       3224498923 3657370039  432871117 206.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       3272020941 5225480974 1953460034 931.5G 16 Hidden FAT16
/dev/sda3                0          0          0     0B 6f unknown
/dev/sda4         50200576  974536369  924335794 440.8G  0 Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
root@ubuntu:/mnt/nfs/volume2/drive2/fpp/test#
```

Comment: You did `fdisk -l /dev/sda`, not `fdisk -l`, so only disk `sda` and it's partitions are listed.

Comment: first, I'd suggest you look at using `clonezilla` https://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable rather than just `dd` ... can you include a copy of the output from `df -l`?

Comment: It seems like the issue is that I was not using AHCI. The disk is nvme and from what I was told on IRC Linux wont bring up a nvme disk that's not set to AHCI